# Module not found: Can't resolve './src/refreshableScrollView

Tags: react-native, antd-mobile

after installing ant mobile in my app i've tryed to use a card component in my app but when i launch the application in web or on my phone with expo I always receive the same error(the full log of the error is: Module not found:

```
Can't resolve './src/refreshableScrollView' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@bang88\react-native-ultimate-listview
```

idk if is needed but every info I have I've posted)', anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently have the same problem and have figured this out.

First you need to install ant mobile using expo instead of npm:
`expo install @ant-design/react-native`

Also install babel-plugin-import:
`expo install babel-plugin-import`

Then modify the `babel.config.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ['import', {libraryName: '@ant-design/react-native'}],
    ],
  };
};
```